# How to achieve this layout in CSS? (where sections overlap each other)

Tags: html, css

[image]

I really don't know what to search in Google so I have to ask here. How do I achieve this design where the title can be above photo and at the same time, the description would adjust down regarding the length of the title (instead of unrespect the DOM flow). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most elegant (and modern) way to achieve this is using `display: grid`. In grid, elements **can overlap** each other. If you just simply want to take the title away from normal DOM flow, then `position: absolute` + some workaround is enough, but to achieve the **layout**, grid is the way to go.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.container h1 {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
.container img {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}
.container p {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x300">
  </img>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing</h1>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit a
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: oh this does it! thanks!

Comment: Well done, Huynh. However, I would suggest not using body as a styled container in answers because that can be confusing for some novices (at least, that was the case for me back when...) Otherwise, excellent answer. Concise, clear and accurate. +1

Comment: @cssyphus I edited it, had been in a hurry when writing that answer. Maybe it's clearer now, thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution using flex;

you'll have to create 2 divs one for content, other for image, and then using flex make them equal height's and width's (if you wish to) then insert your title above these flexed divs with absolute position and then push the paragraph content down to where you wish it to start from.

```
<div class="layout">
      <h2>...headline</h2>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-1">
          ...lipsum
       </div>
       <div class="col-2">
         <img src="...imgSrc" />
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

here's the final version: https://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/5rf680do/